# Js Barcode: generate on the server a raster file of the barcode

Tags: javascript, file, svg, barcode

i'm using Js Barcode for generating barcodes for a web app running on Apache and written in PHP. This library creates barcodes using  tag and calling JsBarcode function. I need to save on the server as a raster file (jpg or png) the generated barcode  but i have no idea how i can do it. Any help?

Comment: I assume you're using the client-side (as opposed to the node) version of that library. Assuming that's the case, since you're generating the barcode on the client, you'll need to send the generated data (from the client) to the server to be saved.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm using the version downloaded from the official website that is a js library. How can i send the barcode from client to server and save it as a raster file? Thanks